# Mapbox Javascript API function event call order

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am only attaching the script tag. Below is the flow of events that happen and the problem I see. I would appreciate any suggestions/advice.

I trigger the businessGeocoder by searching for an address, which triggers the `businessAddress` function inside the `initialize` function, which in turn triggers the `businessLocationClickInfo` function. This works perfectly.

Without refreshing the page I decide to use the employeeResidenceGeocoder by searching for an address, which triggers the `employeeResidenceAddress` function inside the `initialize` function, which in turn triggers the `employeeResidenceLocationClickInfo` function. This works perfectly. too.

Again, without refreshing the page I decide to use the businessGeocoder again by searching for an address, which triggers the `businessAddress` function inside the `initialize` function, which in turn SHOULD trigger the `businessLocationClickInfo` function, but instead, it triggers the `employeeResidenceLocationClickInfo` function. The `employeeResidenceLocationClickInfo` function, while it should have not been called, returns the correct data. I am having a hard time understanding why it is being called instead of the `businessLocationClickInfo` function.

Please note that doing it the other way, using `employeeResidenceGeocoder` first and then `businessGeocoder`, and then back to `employeeResidenceGeocoder` causes the same problem.

Update>> I ran console logs after each line and found out that because the click events are called in the `initialize` function, every time I click on the map both `businessLocationClickInfo` and `employeeResidenceLocationClickInfo` are being called, one replacing the other output div, whereas I want to only call one of them, depending on the geocoder. But I still haven't found a way/order to fix it.

```
 <script>

    var map;
    var businessGeocoder;
    var employeeResidenceGeocoder;
    var businessLocationClickFeature;
    var employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature;
    
    var screenPoint;
    var address;
    var geocodeFeature;
    var geocodePopup;
    var geocodeCensusTract;
    var geocodeCensusBlockGroup;
    

    var businessLocationPolygon;
    var employeeResidenceLocationPolygon; 
  
    
     
    function initialize() {
        businessGeocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
                               accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
                               flyTo: {
                                      speed: 100
                               },
                               zoom: 17,
                               placeholder: "Search for a business location",
                               mapboxgl: mapboxgl
                               })
        employeeResidenceGeocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
                               accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
                               flyTo: {
                                      speed: 100
                               },
                               zoom: 17,
                               placeholder: "Search for an employee's residence",
                               mapboxgl: mapboxgl
                               })                       
                              
        // // // adds geocoder outside of map (inside of map would make it a 'map control')
        // document.getElementById('geocoder1').appendChild(businessGeocoder.onAdd(map));
        // document.getElementById('geocoder2').appendChild(employeeResidenceGeocoder.onAdd(map));
     
        map.addControl(businessGeocoder);
        map.addControl(employeeResidenceGeocoder);

        businessGeocoder.on('result', businessAddress);
        employeeResidenceGeocoder.on('result', employeeResidenceAddress);
        
    }
    

    function businessAddress (obj) {
        address = obj.result.place_name;
        $(".geocode-result-area").html('<b>Geocoded Business Address: </b>' + address + '<br/><div class="medium-font">Click the blue address pin on the map for updated results.</div>');
        $(".geocode-click-result-area").html("");
        map.on('click', businessLocationClickInfo);
    }
    
    
    function employeeResidenceAddress (obj) {
        address = obj.result.place_name;
        $(".geocode-result-area").html('<b>Geocoded Employee Residence Address: </b>' + address + '<br/><div class="medium-font">Click the blue address pin on the map for updated results.</div>');
        $(".geocode-click-result-area").html("");
        map.on('click', employeeResidenceLocationClickInfo);
    }
    
    
    
    function businessLocationClickInfo (obj) { 
        businessLocationClickFeature = map.queryRenderedFeatures(obj.point, {
            layers: ['tract-4332-1sbuyl','blockgroups-4332-9mehvk','businesslocation'] 
        });

        if (businessLocationClickFeature.length == 3) {
            $(".geocode-click-result-area").html('<br/>This area meets the <span style="background-color:yellow">business location criteria</span> based on the following thresholds:'
                                                 + '<table><tr><td>Renewal Community</td><td>' + businessLocationClickFeature[2].properties.Inquiry1 + '</td></tr>'
                                                 + '<tr><td>CT & BG Poverty Rate &#8805; 20%</td><td>' + businessLocationClickFeature[2].properties.Inquiry2 + '</td></tr></table>'
                                                 + '<p><b>' + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.CountyName + " County" + '<br/>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.NAMELSAD + '<br/>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[1].properties.NAMELSAD + '</b></p>'
                                                 +'<table><tr><th></th><th>Poverty Rate</th></tr><tr><td>CT ' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.TRACTCE + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td></tr><tr><td>BG '
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[1].properties.BLKGRPCE + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[1].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td></tr></table>'
                                                );
        }
        else {
            $(".geocode-click-result-area").html('<br/> This area <u style = "color:red;">does not</u> meet the business location criteria based on the following thresholds:'
                                                 + '<table><tr><td>Renewal Community</td><td>No</td></tr>'
                                                 + '<tr><td>CT & BG Poverty Rate &#8805; 20%</td><td>No</td></tr></table>'
                                                 + '<p><b>' + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.CountyName + " County" + '<br/>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.NAMELSAD + '<br/>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[1].properties.NAMELSAD + '</b></p>'
                                                 + '<table><tr><th></th><th>Poverty Rate</th></tr><tr><td>CT ' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.TRACTCE + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[0].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td></tr><tr><td>BG '
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[1].properties.BLKGRPCE + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + businessLocationClickFeature[1].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td></tr></table>'
                                                 );
        }
    }

    
    
    
    function employeeResidenceLocationClickInfo (obj) { 
        employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature = map.queryRenderedFeatures(obj.point, {
            layers: ['tract-4332-1sbuyl','blockgroups-4332-9mehvk','employeeresidencelocation'] 
        });
        if (employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature.length == 3) {
            $(".geocode-click-result-area").html('<br/>This area meets the <span style="background-color:yellow">employee residence location criteria</span> based on the following thresholds:'
                                                 + '<table><tr><td>Renewal Community</td><td>' + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[2].properties.Inquiry1 + '</td></tr>'
                                                 + '<tr><td>CT % LMI &#8805; 70%</td><td>' + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[2].properties.Inquiry2 + '</td></tr>'
                                                 + '<tr><td>CT & all BG Poverty Rate &#8805; 20%</td><td>' + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[2].properties.Inquiry3 + '</td></tr></table>'
                                                 + '<p><b>' + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.CountyName + " County" + '<br/>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.NAMELSAD + '<br/>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[1].properties.NAMELSAD + '</b></p>'
                                                 + '<table id="CensusTable"><tr><th></th><th>Poverty Rate</th><th>LMI</th></tr><tr><td>CT ' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.TRACTCE + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.LMIPerc + "%" + '</td></tr>');
   
            var BGsin20PovertyCT = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
                { layers: ['blockgroups-4332-9mehvk'],
                filter: ["==", "TRACTCE", employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.TRACTCE] 
                });
            var unique = [];
            var distinct = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < BGsin20PovertyCT.length; i++ ){
                if (!unique[BGsin20PovertyCT[i].properties.BLKGRPCE]){
                distinct.push(BGsin20PovertyCT[i]);
                unique[BGsin20PovertyCT[i].properties.BLKGRPCE] = 1;
                }
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < distinct.length; i++ ){
                $("#CensusTable").append('<tr><td>BG ' + distinct[i].properties.BLKGRPCE + '</td><td>'
                                         + distinct[i].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td><td>-</td></tr></table>'
                                         );
            } 
        }
        else {
            $(".geocode-click-result-area").html('<br/> This area <u style = "color:red;">does not</u> meet the employee residence location criteria based on the following thresholds:'
                                                 + '<table><tr><td>Renewal Community</td><td>No</td></tr>'
                                                 + '<tr><td>CT % LMI &#8805; 70%</td><td>No</td></tr>'
                                                 + '<tr><td>CT & all BG Poverty Rate &#8805; 20%</td><td>No</td></tr></table>'
                                                 + '<p><b>' + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.CountyName + " County" + '<br/>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.NAMELSAD + '<br/>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[1].properties.NAMELSAD + '</b></p>'
                                                 + '<table id="CensusTable"><tr><th></th><th>Poverty Rate</th><th>LMI</th></tr><tr><td>CT ' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.TRACTCE + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td><td>' 
                                                 + employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.LMIPerc + "%" + '</td></tr>');
                var BGsin20PovertyCT = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
                    { layers: ['blockgroups-4332-9mehvk'],
                    filter: ["==", "TRACTCE", employeeResidenceLocationClickFeature[0].properties.TRACTCE] 
                    });
                var unique = [];
                var distinct = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < BGsin20PovertyCT.length; i++ ){
                    if (!unique[BGsin20PovertyCT[i].properties.BLKGRPCE]){
                    distinct.push(BGsin20PovertyCT[i]);
                    unique[BGsin20PovertyCT[i].properties.BLKGRPCE] = 1;
                    }
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < distinct.length; i++ ){
                    $("#CensusTable").append('<tr><td>BG ' + distinct[i].properties.BLKGRPCE + '</td><td>'
                                             + distinct[i].properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td><td>-</td></tr></table>'
                                             );
                } 
        }
    }
    




    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3l1bmdhaGxpbSIsImEiOiJjanJyejQyeHUyNGwzNGFuMzdzazh1M2k1In0.TcQEe2aebuQZ4G7d827A9Q';
    
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/kyungahlim/ckd226uao1p7i1iqo8ag2ewmu',
    center: [-95.925, 29.575],
    zoom: 7
    });

    
    map.on('load', initialize); 

    

    
    // // Center the map on the coordinates of any clicked symbol from the 'symbols' layer.
    // map.on('click', 'symbols', function(e) {
    // map.flyTo({
    // center: e.features[0].geometry.coordinates
    // });
    // });
     
    // // Change the cursor to a pointer when the it enters a feature in the 'symbols' layer.
    // map.on('mouseenter', 'symbols', function() {
    // map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    // });
     
    // // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
    // map.on('mouseleave', 'symbols', function() {
    // map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    // });



var geojson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-95.925, 29.575]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Mapbox',
      description: 'Washington, D.C.'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-122.414, 37.776]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Mapbox',
      description: 'San Francisco, California'
    }
  }]
};


// // geocode the typed-in address, zoom to the location, and put a pin on address
// function codeAddress() {
//     sAddress = document.getElementById('inputTextAddress').value;
//     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) {
//         //latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
//         //longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
//         coordinate = results[0].geometry.location;

//         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
//             if (GeocodeMarker){
//                 GeocodeMarker.setMap(null);
//             }
// //            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
// //            PuppyMap.fitBounds(bounds);
//             PuppyMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
//             PuppyMap.setZoom(14);
//             GeocodeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
//                 map:PuppyMap,
//                 position: results[0].geometry.location,
//                 animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
//                 icon: housePin,
//                 zoom: 0
//             });

//         }
//         else{
//             alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
//         }
//     });
// }



  var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(document.createElement('div'))
    .setLngLat( [-95.925, 29.575])
    .addTo(map);                              


// // add markers to map
// geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

//   // create a HTML element for each feature
//   var el = document.createElement('div');
//   el.className = 'marker';

//   // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
//   new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
//     .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
//     .addTo(map);
// });

</script>
```